# Excel VBA script on formatting shapes

Tags: vba, excel

I am making an interactive map, with two sheets. First sheet is the map sheet with line shapes, second is the database.

I would like to add a colouring function according to the line shapes which is based on the values in the database.

I've made a plan for the easier undertanding which can be found here: http://www.speedyshare.com/gWJwd/plan.xlsm

Here is the code I've tried:

```
If Target.Address = Sheets("Data").Range("$C$4:$C$9") Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = 10
            Sheets("Map").Shapes(cl.Value).Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
        Case Is = 20
            Sheets("Map").Shapes(cl.Value).Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlue
        Case Is = 30
            Sheets("Map").Shapes(cl.Value).Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
    End Select
End If
```

Comment: You will get better responses if you include in your question the exact code that you've tried.

Comment: Well, I've tried the following code, but somehow it is not working.

`code` 
If Target.Address = Sheets("Data").Range("$C$4:$C$9") Then
Select Case Target.Value
Case Is = 10
Sheets("Map").Shapes(cl.Value).Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
Case Is = 20
Sheets("Map").Shapes(cl.Value).Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlue
Case Is = 30
Sheets("Map").Shapes(cl.Value).Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
End Select
End If

Comment: I added the code to the question for easier readability.